# Add www-data to group

Tags: linux, www-data, usermod

I have a directory with the following details:

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 root devs 4.0K Sep  9 14:57 project_dev
```

Now I want `www-data` (Apache daemon) to have an access to this directory, so in my mind I am planning to add `www-data` to group devs. However I fear that I would cause wreckage if I execute this:

```
usermod -a -G devs www-data
```

Inputs please.

Answer (score 5):

You won't break anything, but you might cause a security issue, since anyone accessing the www-data account (php scripts, unpatched, hacked pages, etc.) will get read/write access to everything that the 'devs' group has.

"www-data" already has read access to that folder, try limiting the write access to just the files it really really needs to write to.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback, I'd think of this approach because I'm about to install WebSVN. That `project_dev` is a repository. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't he just change the group to www-data and add the dev group to www-data to give access to www-data and avoid the security risk?

Comment: @Choy: yes, that would work too. But then the devs would have access to all the www-data stuff (which is sometimes OK, sometimes not). Maybe a separate group, and adding the www-data and required devs to it?